# Copy email as document link in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using the "New Look" Outlook on Windows 11 and selecting an email in the Inbox and hitting Ctrl+C no longer copies the email as a document that can be pasted into other Office programs.   The "Copy" section of the context menu from right clicking also doesn't work.

How can I do this in the "New Look" Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
As mentioned in this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375979/how-to-copy-an-attachment-within-the-new-ms-outloo), you can vote for the feedback as Soki Guo mentioned:
[image]

---

Based on my test, i cannot hit Ctrl+C to copy the email to other Office program as attachment in New Outlook. It's suggested that you could save it first and insert it to other program.

[image]

Comment: None of 'Save', 'Share to Teams' or 'Send to OneNote' are on my context menu.   Could be an IT policy.   But strange that its apparent only in New Look.  Hmm.

Comment: Ah, those are in View -> View Settings -> Mail -> Customize actions.   They're not in 'Get Add-Ins'.   Let me see if this is a workaround, at least.

Comment: Damnit.  No, that setting only adds small icons to the preview panel.  Not the context menu, and not to the ribbon that you see when looking at a message in a window.  #%@#!

Comment: Agree with you, the save option is available in Reading pane or when we double click to open it.